# Group multidimensional php array outputs on single row

Tags: php, html, arrays, multidimensional-array, columnsorting

**How can I achieve the result in Table #2 with the foreach in Table #1
See sample code and the desired output.**

```
<?php

$array = [
["id"=>1,"day"=>"1","amount"=>345],
["id"=>2,"day"=>"1","amount"=>66],
["id"=>1,"day"=>"3","amount"=>12],
["id"=>2,"day"=>"1","amount"=>69],
["id"=>1,"day"=>"4","amount"=>82],
["id"=>1,"day"=>"5","amount"=>12.5],
["id"=>2,"day"=>"3","amount"=>35],
["id"=>2,"day"=>"4","amount"=>89],
["id"=>2,"day"=>"5","amount"=>9],
["id"=>1,"day"=>"2","amount"=>15],
["id"=>2,"day"=>"4","amount"=>67]
];

$size = count($array);

$table = "<table><tr><th>Table #1</th><th>Monday</th><th>Tuesday</th><th>Wednesday</th><th>Thursday</th><th>Friday</th></tr>";

for($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
$table .= ($array[$i]["id"] === 1)? "<tr class='service1'><td>Service #1</td>" : "<tr class='service2'><td>Service #2</td>";
$table .= ($array[$i]["day"] == 1)? "<td>{$array[$i]["amount"]}</td>" : "<td></td>";
$table .= ($array[$i]["day"] == 2)? "<td>{$array[$i]["amount"]}</td>" : "<td></td>";
$table .= ($array[$i]["day"] == 3)? "<td>{$array[$i]["amount"]}</td>" : "<td></td>";
$table .= ($array[$i]["day"] == 4)? "<td>{$array[$i]["amount"]}</td>" : "<td></td>";
$table .= ($array[$i]["day"] == 5)? "<td>{$array[$i]["amount"]}</td>" : "<td></td>";
$table .= "</tr>";
}
$table .= "</table>";

echo $table;

?>
```

Desired result: https://jsfiddle.net/dvporua6/

Comment: Add another loop inside that cycles through the days.

Comment: What's the logic?

Answer (score 1):

What comes into my mind is that you'll probably need to restructure the output coming from initial array first.

Since table number two has empty days, I'll suggest pre-fill another array first so that you take care of it initially.

Then you sub divide your multi dimensional array into `services -> weeks -> days` row format.

To better understand what I'm saying, here's a dump representation of it:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 345
                    [2] => 15
                    [3] => 12
                    [4] => 82
                    [5] => 12.5
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 66
                    [2] => 
                    [3] => 35
                    [4] => 89
                    [5] => 9
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 69
                    [2] => 
                    [3] => 
                    [4] => 67
                    [5] => 
                )

        )

)
```

So the parent array consists of the `services`. Under one service, it needs to have another level since you can have collision of days, I'm assuming this can represent as weeks.

And of course under the weeks are the days and their corresponding amount.

Now if they are placed in row format correctly, from that format, it should be fairly straightforward to create a table similar to this:

[image]

Now to get to that structure, we need to build off a new one first. Then render an array structure with empty values.

```
$array2 = []; // initial array container
$num_days_per_week = 5;
$num_group_type = array_count_values(array_column($array, 'id')); // get the services and how many days in each service
foreach ($num_group_type as $service => $batch) { // loop service group
    $batches = ceil($batch / $num_days_per_week); // get number of weeks for each service
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $batches; $i++) { // pre fill
        $array2[$service][] = array_combine(range(1, $num_days_per_week), array_fill(0, $num_days_per_week, null));
    }
}
```

This block should give us an empty array like this:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 
                    [2] => 
                    [3] => 
                    [4] => 
                    [5] => 
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 
                    [2] => 
                    [3] => 
                    [4] => 
                    [5] => 
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 
                    [2] => 
                    [3] => 
                    [4] => 
                    [5] => 
                )

        )

)
```

The next step should be populating said new array structure:

```
// populating the structured array
$week = 0;
foreach ($array as $val) {
    if (empty($array2[$val['id']][$week][$val['day']])) {
        $array2[$val['id']][$week][$val['day']] = $val['amount']; // set the appropriate day -> amount value
    } else {
        // but if there are two mondays, push the next monday to next week
        $num_batch = ceil($num_group_type[$val['id']] / $num_days_per_week);
        for ($next_possible_week = ($week + 1); $next_possible_week <= $num_batch; $j++) {
            if (empty($array2[$val['id']][$next_possible_week][$val['day']])) {
                // if possible to fill the next, fill and stop
                $array2[$service][$next_possible_week][$val['day']] = $val['amount'];
                break;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Basically its just putting / transferring the values from `$array` to newly structured `$array2`.

If there's no value set for that `day amount` key pair, set it. If its set already, push it to the next available week.

After that, you'll have the structure with the correct values in their proper place. Next step is just building up the markup. The style is up to you, but the simplest would be just use the table tag like what you did previously.

```
echo '<table border=1>';
echo '<tr><th>Table #2</th><th>Monday</th><th>Tuesday</th><th>Wednesday</th><th>Thursday</th><th>Friday</th></tr>';
foreach ($array2 as $service => $weeks) {
    foreach ($weeks as $week) {
        echo "<tr class=\"service{$service}\">";
        echo "<td>Service #{$service}</td>";
        foreach ($week as $day => $amount) {
            $amount = empty($amount) ? '&nbsp;' : $amount;
            echo "<td>{$amount}</td>";
        }
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Here's the fiddle that you can play with:

https://www.tehplayground.com/o96tPV6rAwffsUPn

Comment: Perfect tnxx man !!

Comment: When you add this data in the array it breaks:
    ["id"=>1,"day"=>"1","amount"=>90]

Comment: The error was here:
$array2[$service][$next_possible_week][$val['day']] = $val['amount'];
Correct:
$array2[$val['id']][$next_possible_week][$val['day']] = $val['amount'];